# Google Maps API - Autocomplete - How to set type as default by "Addresses"?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to use this script: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

In this DEMO, we can see this:

[image]

I want to remove these inputs and set as default position: "Addresses". Finally I would like to use only search input (without map and other efects).

What I have to edit in script to set this type for "Addresses" as default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set it by default and bypass the click, use:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { types: ['address'] });
```

Instead of:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

See "Add Autocomplete for places and addresses" section of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete for details on your other options.

Answer (score -1):

HTML from that example:

```
 <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
 <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>
```

Code to read it:

```
    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, types) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        autocomplete.setTypes(types);
      });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
```

Set the autocomplete types field to `['address']`

It is also described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3):

> **address** instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.